# Question on fingering for piano

Tags: theory, piano, technique, fingering, keyboard

http://www.frederickhodges.com/fundamentalsofpianotechniquepart1.html

I read that in fingering the major and minor arpeggios, only use the first, second, fourth, and fifth fingers, replacing the third with the fourth for a stronger fourth finger. Is this accurate/efficient, or should I stick to the common use of the 3 finger instead of the fourth?

Comment: It’s all about what feels comfortable to your hands. I certainly don’t think there’s a standard fingering everyone has to use for arpeggios. Granted, there are clearly bad fingerings, but for any given group of notes, there is usually more than one good fingering also. It all depends on what feels comfortable to you and allows you to execute the arpeggios the most proficiently and without unnecessary tension.

Answer (score 1):

The "standard" fingering for the right hand is to use 2 4 when the interval between those two notes is a fourth, and 2 3 when it is a third.

For the left hand, if the interval between 2 1 is a fourth, you can use either 3 or 4 on the other note.

Mr Hodges is entitled to his own opinions, of course - including the first sentence of the biography on his website claiming he is "Hailed by the press as one of the best concert pianists in the world."

Answer (score 1):

I use the fingering suggested in Schmitt - Preparatory Exercises (a useful book to get with a great appendix containing tons of scales, arpeggios, broken chords, chord passages etc.)

5421 for all LH arpeggios except where you have a white key to black key major third, i.e. D major, E major and A major, in which case 5321, as the physical distance is slightly larger here. In fact, apart from these, Scmhmitt doesn't even suggest 5321 as an alternative, so 5421 must have been the standard back in the 1800s.

Not only does 5421 strengthen the fourth and fifth fingers but if you are arpeggiating over more than one octave you will find you are set up better for the subsequent octave when you bring 4 over 1 (or 1 under 4 in descending).

Also, as my teacher pointed out, if you are generally using 1245 on the RH (which is my preference), then the LH 1245 descending is symmetrical with this, so using the fourth finger on the left hand may require less brain "processing power" over the long run. He also pointed out that LH 5421 puts your wrist in a more neutral position (test it out and see!)